# Angular 6 : Cannot load child route on page load

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have an issue reloading a page when on a feature module route, for example; I can navigate to

http://example.com/#/dashboard

but if I then force a page refresh in the browser I get the following navigation error:

```
Router Event: NavigationError
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationError(id: 1, url: '/dashboard', 
error: TypeError: undefined is not a function)
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationError {id: 1, url: "/dashboard", 
error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at webpackAsyncContext (ht…}
```

---

My routing files read as follows:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    { 
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true, useHash: true } )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: DashboardComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module'

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module'
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        DashboardRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module'
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module'

import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    DashboardModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Why are you using hash? But anyway i see noo `DashboardModule` here.

Comment: @Antoniossss Does the hash make a difference? I have amended my question to include the dashboard and app modules. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I don't see any fault in ur code, just try by removing useHash and re run

Comment: Hi @arunkumar I tried removing the hash but I still get the same error :(

Comment: I can see `DashboardModule` module included in `AppModule` imports. No need to include that module if you are using lazy loading

Comment: @planet_hunter "no need" is bad pick of words - you MUST NOT include that as it will prevent lazy loading from happening - module will be imported  right away.

Comment: @Antoniossss That makes sense! Thanks!! I can't edit my comment though..

Comment: But to be honest, maybe this is somehow related. @prime remove DashboardModule imports from AppModule. And check if navigation still works.

Comment: Well that's the reason I said `no need`, I ran into a similar problem and my understanding was the same routes are getting registered twice! :)

Comment: planet_hunter & @antoniossss star men!!! thank you, fixed my issue by removing the modules from app.module :) I shall mark an answer as correct if you wish to make the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lazy loading you MUST NOT include lazy loaded module as import (nor you can use TS import from that module) because it will be loaded along importing module.

planet_hunter takes a lot of credit here for spotting your imports.